# Measure polynomial arc-length between given range

Tags: polynomials, arc-length

Is there a way to measure the arc-length of a curve created by a 4-degrees polynomial, between a given range?

For example, I want to measure the length of the polynomial $-\frac{1}{200}x^3+x+1$ between [0,10] (the blue line in the image below):

[image]

This is just an example, the only thing I know is that the range always starts at $x=0$, and the polynomial is a 4-degree polynomial. Is there a formula to measure the arc-length of the section?

Comment: Length of a polynomial?

Comment: @Jakobian the length of a polynomial between a given range...

Comment: The way to calculate arc-length of a curve given parametrically is to integrate speed, where speed is the magnitude of the velocity vector. In the case of a function $f(x)$ (such as a polynomial), the parametric curve is $t \to (t, f(t))$, the velocity is $t \to (1, f'(t))$, the speed is $t \to \sqrt{1+(f'(t))^2}$, and the arc-length between $x=a$ and $x=b$ is $\int_a^b \sqrt{1+(f'(t))^2} \mathrm{dt}$.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Thank you! But why in a comment and not an answer? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to calculate arc-length of a curve given parametrically is to integrate speed, where speed is the magnitude of the velocity vector.

For a function $f(x)$ on an interval $[a, b]$, the parametric curve is
$$t \to (t, f(t)),$$
the velocity is
$$t \to (1, f'(t)),$$
the speed is
$$t \to \sqrt{1+\left(f'(t)\right)^2},$$
and the arc-length is therefore
$$\int_a^b \sqrt{1+\left(f'(t)\right)^2}\mathrm{dt}.$$
So for your example, $f(x) = -\frac{1}{200}x^3+x+1$, $f'(x) = -\frac{3}{100}x^2+1$, and the arclength between $0$ and $10$ is
$$\int_0^{10} \sqrt{1+\left(1-\frac{3t^2}{200}\right)^2}\mathrm{dt}.$$
I don't know whether that integral can be solved analytically, but it is worth noting that if you just need the number, [Wolfram Alpha does the algebra of deriving the integrand for you](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arclength%20of%20y%3D-%281%2F200%29x%5E3%20%2B%20x%20%2B%201%20between%200%20and%2010).

Answer (score -2):

This may be a dumb question, but isn't $\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{1+(1- 3t^2/200)^2 }  dt$ = $\sqrt{\int_{a}^{b}1+(1- 3t^2/200)^2 }  dt$  which is easily expanded to $\sqrt{\int_{a}^{b}(2-3t^2/100 + 9t^4/40,000)} dt $ and integrated as a polynomial to $\sqrt{2t - t^3/100 + 9t^5/(5*40,000) +C  }$ between a and b?

This is my first use of Latex, so bear with me!